# How to re-locate the bar-chart location when map zoom in/out

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg

The code now can put bird count data on Google map with SVG.

However, new problems have come with,the bar chart can not be re-locate when the map zoom in/out.

When I zoom in/out the map, I want the bar chart to be locate on the right location with it's (lat,lng),but the code now has this problem.

How can I fix it?  Can someone teach me?

My CSV :https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6SUWnrBmDwSWkI4bVNtOTNSOTA/view?usp=sharing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
.gmap {
   display: block;
   width: 1000px;
   height: 800px;
}
.stations, .stations svg { position: absolute; }

.stations svg { width: 120px; height: 30px; padding-right: 100px; font: 12px     sans-serif; }

.stations circle { fill: yellow; stroke: black; stroke-width: 1.5px; }
</style>
<body>
<div class="gmap" id="map-canvas"></div>  
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script>
d3.csv("223-loc.csv", function(d) {
   return {
    date: d.date,
    location: d.location,
    lat: +d.lat,
    lng: +d.lng ,
    birdName: d.birdName,
    count:+d.count
  };
}, function(error, rows) {
 console.log(rows[0].lat);

  function BarChartOverlay(chartData, map){
    this.map_ = map;
    this.chartData_ = chartData;
    this.div_=null;
    this.setMap(map);
}

  BarChartOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

BarChartOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function(){
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('id','chartDiv');

    var chartArea = d3.select(div).append("svg");

    this.chartData_.forEach(function(item){

       var pos = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(new     google.maps.LatLng(item.lat, item.lng));

       var bar = chartArea
              .append("rect")
              .attr("x", pos.x)
              .attr("y", pos.y)
              .attr("width", 5)
              .attr("height", item.count)
              .attr("fill-opacity", '0.5')
              .attr("fill", 'purple');
});
this.div_ = div;
this.chartArea_ = chartArea;
var panes = this.getPanes();
panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);    

};

BarChartOverlay.prototype.draw = function(){
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();
        var sw =         overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.map_.getBounds().getSouthWest());
    var ne =     overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.map_.getBounds().getNorthEast());
    var chartAreaSize = sw.x + ' ' +  ne.y + ' ' + (ne.x - sw.x) + ' ' + (sw.y - ne.y);
this.chartArea_.attr('viewBox',chartAreaSize);
};

BarChartOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function(){
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    this.div_ = null;
    };

function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8, center: new
                 google.maps.LatLng(23.7147979, 120.7105502)
            };
            var chartData = rows;
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-    canvas'), mapOptions);
            var overlay = new BarChartOverlay(chartData, map);
}
initialize();
 });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layer is not smart enough, you have to tell him to repaint:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    overlay.draw();
});
```

However, for your case above code simply did not work for me (have no idea why, it works for all other cases I have tried), so I explicitly added `map` to your layer again, causing it to repaint:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    overlay.setMap(map);
});
```